Is it possible to create pages locally in the Shopify environment?
I created sections locally, but I don't see a way to create pages locally. More, if I create a page using the shopify editor, I don't see any of its content when I pull the latest changes. Are pages special? How does this environment deals with pages?

under pages you can create pages and select the template, when you want to create template please go to theme editor and under templates create page template it should be look like "Page.name of your page template.liquid".
